# How to replace string on pandas dataframe before certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

Here's my dataset

```
Id  Text
1   Animation_and_Cartoon - Comics and Anime/Cartoon_and_anime
2   Animation_and_Cartoon - Comics and Anime/Manga_and_anime
```

Expected output is all `_` before `-` is replaced by ' ', but after `-` is not

```
Id  Text
1   Animation_and_Cartoon - Comics and Anime/Cartoon_and_anime
2   Animation_and_Cartoon - Comics and Anime/Manga_and_anime
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(
             r'^([^-]+)',
             lambda m: m.group().replace('_and_',' and '),
             regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   Id                                                        Text
0   1  Animation and Cartoon - Comics and Anime/Cartoon_and_anime
1   2    Animation and Cartoon - Comics and Anime/Manga_and_anime
```